# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x) = nx\int_n^{nx+1}y^{-2}e^{n/y}dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Let $\mathbb{R}_+ = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0\}$ and let's look at the sequence of functions $f_n: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R},$
>
> $$f_n(x) = nx\int_n^{nx+1}y^{-2}e^{n/y}dy$$
>
> where  $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $ n \in \mathbb{N}_1$.
>
> Show that the sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise in the set $\mathbb{R}_+$. Is the convergence uniform?

This turned out to be a bit notorious. I cannot even see how to approach this since computing the limit in order to find if $f_n$ converges pointwise isn't very straightforward.

Comment: Let $v=1/y$ then the $dv=\frac{-1}{y^2}dy$ and you have: $$f_n(x)=nx\int_{1/(nx+1)}^{1/n} e^{nv}\,dv$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution $u = e^{n/y}$ then $du = ny^{-2} e^{n/y} dy$ hence

$f_n(x) = nx \int_e^{e^{n/ (nx+1)}} y^{-2}(-1)y^2\dfrac{1}{n}du=-x  \int_e^{e^{n/ (nx+1)}} u du $ , and this is easy to compute.

Answer (score 0):

First write

$$ nx \int_n^{nx+1} \frac{1}{y^2} e^{n/y} dy = x \int_n^{nx+1} \frac{n^2}{y^2} e^{n/y} \frac{dy}{n} $$

Next perform a change of variables $z = y/n$, so

$$ = x \int_{1}^{x + 1/n} \frac{1}{z^2} e^{1/z} dz $$

then invert with $v = 1/z$ to get

$$ = x \int_{1 / (x + 1/n)}^1 e^v dv = x [ e - e^{1/(x+1/n)} ]$$

Pointwise convergence to $x[e - e^{1/x}]$ follows pretty easily. Uniform convergence or not requires an analysis of the behavior near $x = 0$ and near $x = \infty$.